# Running a Java Robot from a SwingWorker thread?

Tags: java, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread, awtrobot

I have been trying to use a `Robot` in a `SwingWorker` class and my returns "gracefully" when something like `robotInstance.keyPress(..)` is called. I can instantiate an instance but cannot use it.

Does the Robot class have some relation with Swing and the EDT? Should I wrap the calls to `Robot` in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)` call?